# Intercative script for remote ssh login

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting

I'm approaching for the first time to bash scripting in the latest days. I'd like to create something very easy that let me connect to multiple servers/devices. My idea is having a list (txt file) of all devices with FQDN and description. The script should read the list and show me all the devices as a list (adding an ID for example). Then I should be able to insert ID device and then the script connect me to that device.
How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad to be suitable for this site. I would suggest that you [edit] the question so that it's more focussed. See also [ask] and [help/on-topic]. It's also useful to take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `select` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t servers < input_file.txt

[[ ${#servers[@]} -eq 0 ]] && exit 1

select server in "${servers[@]}"; do
   IFS= read -r -p "Enter username: " username
   ssh "${username:-default}@${server:-${servers[0]}}"
done
```

- `readarray` stores the servers in an array. You can also store the servers manually without the file: `servers=(server1.com server2.com)`
- `select` then prompts you to enter a number corresponding to one of the servers
- If you input a wrong option, `${server:-${servers[0]}}` will use the first server address in your file
- `read` will prompt for a username
- If you input empty username (for example you press enter when prompted by `read`), `${username:-default}` will use `default` username that you choose

Comment: thanks @PesaThe. It works. Now i'm searching how to add more features, for example specify which account to use (I have devices where i can access with local account or ldap account).

Comment: @ruzzetto You can prompt for the username with `read` command. See my updated answer.